# What's the magic behind this flatMap code?

Tags: scala, list, flatmap

I'm learning Scala and in the below code using flatMap
(taken from  [filter with flatmap or collect](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/04/filter-with-flatmap-or-collect.html))

I have

```
list flatMap {
    case st: String => Some(st)
    case _ => None
}
```

It works on `List[Any]` and yield `List[String]`

```
scala> List(1, "A") flatMap {
     | case st: String => Some(st)
     | case _  => None
     | }
res21: List[String] = List(A)
```

Now I'm confused about the `types` here. As I thought, `flatMap` works on some kinds of `monad` which works as a transformation from `M[M[A]] -> M[A]`.

The code bellow is easy to understand,

```
def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
    case ms: List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case e => List(e)
}
```

since both case return a `List[Any]`, which is still the same type of `ls: List[Any]`.

But why `Some[String]` and `None` are acceptable in the `flatMap` of a `List[Any]` ?

Besides, it seems like `None` is completely ignored rather then treated as a serious value ? I was thinking there maybe some kinds of compacting steps to get rid of such values, like:

```
[1,2,3].concat([,,2,2])
// => (6) [1, 2, 3, empty × 2, 2]
[1,2,3].concat([,,4]).filter(Boolean)
// => (4) [1,2,3,4]
```

Can someone explain these? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I thought, flatMap works on some kinds of monad which works as a transformation from M[M[A]] -> M[A].

Scala `flatMap` is more general (which some people don't like).

If you look at [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatMap[B](f:A=%3Escala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):List[B]), it's enough for the function passed to `List#flatMap` to return `GenTraversableOnce[SomeType]`, not `List[SomeType]`. And even though `Option` doesn't extend `GenTraversableOnce`, there is an [implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Option$.html#option2Iterable[A](xo:Option[A]):Iterable[A]) between them which gets applied here.

> Besides, it seems like None is completely ignored rather then treated as a serious value ?

`None` corresponds to an empty collection, `Some(x)` to a single-element collection. So you have e.g.

```
Some(1) ++ Some(2) ++ None ++ Some(3) ==
List(1) ++ List(2) ++ List() ++ List(3) ==
List(1,2,3)
```

Or, in your terms, you don't have `[1,2,3,,,4]` (which doesn't make sense), but `[[1],[2],[3],[],[],[4]]`.

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is not restricted to nested collections of the same type. The value returned by the function passed to `flatMap` can be any collection type. `flatMap` will take each element in that collection and append it to the result collection. `Option[T]` works like a collection of 0 or 1 elements, so `flatMap` works as it would with a `List`, `Vector`, `Array` or other collections.

However in this specific case you would actually use `collect` rather than `flatMap`:

```
list.collect{ case s: String => s }
```